# Why does the wildcard not work?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, wildcard

my bind config

```
carrie     IN A     192.253.253.4
*.carrie   IN A     192.253.253.6
*.test.carrie IN A  192.253.253.7
```

execute

```
nslookup  carrie 
Address: 192.253.253.4

nslookup a.test.carrie
Address: 192.253.253.7
```

but when I execute `nslookup test.carrie`

```
*** Can't find test.carrie: No answer
```

Comment: Is there anything useful in the nameserver logs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wildcard is working fine, which is why `a.test.carrie` resolves. Your issue is that `test.carrie` doesn't resolve.

The reason is simply that you haven't got a record for `test.carrie`.

`*.test.carrie` matches immediate subdomains of `test.carrie`, but matches neither `test.carrie` itself, nor any subdomains of subdomains of `test.carrie`.

Add another record without the wildcard.

Comment: why test.carrie dosen`t match wildchard *.carrie

Comment: @leo I'm pretty sure it's because `*.test.carrie` partially defines `test.carrie`. Does `test2.carrie` resolve? If so, try adding `*.test2.carrie` and see if it breaks. Remember to allow time for your DNS cache to expire for accurate testing.

Comment: nslookup test2.carrie Address: 192.253.253.6  after add *.test2.carrie IN A 192.253.253.11 execute nslookup test2.carrie *** Can't find test2.carrie: No answer

Comment: @leo As I thought, there's your answer. Once you add a wildcarded subdomain, BIND will no longer match that subdomain with the wildcard. This is almost certainly expected behaviour

Comment: @Dan Your wording there in the comment is a little off but you're correct. Wildcards match *beneath* the scope of a dot.